# No puedo usar el <p:fileUpload .. cuando lo coloco en una pagina xhtml deja de funcionar todos los elementos contenidos en el bloque form

Tags: java, archivo, primefaces, netbeans-8.2, fileupload

Tengo un problema al ingresar los datos a un formulario, cuando lo hago ingresando fechas y texto no hay problema, sube sin problemas a la base de datos, pero al poner la etiqueta :

```
 <p:fileUpload mode="simple"  value="#{formularioController.cargar}" />
```

No sube, es mas el boton de subida se queda en posición activa y no hace nada, no da mensaje de error y cuando le pongo un paro en el controller, no entra al controller, se para antes de ni siquiera entrar al controller, que en su parte del archivo tiene esto:

```
private UploadedFile cargar;
public UploadedFile getCargar() {
    return cargar;
}
public void setCargar(UploadedFile file) throws IOException {
    this.cargar = file;
}
```

Pensaba que es mi web.xml
pero esta la importación como dice el manual de:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Si retiro esta etiqueta ("p:fileUpload...") el formulario funciona de maravilla. 
Leí la documentación oficial de primefaces y estoy seguro que lo estoy usando según lo recomendado.
esta dentro de un:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

y es efectivamente todo dentro del form que deja de funcionar cuando pongo esta etiqueta, tal vez me falta importar algo, no estoy seguro ya no se donde mas buscar. Espero me puedan dar una mano.
mis librerias son:

[image: librerias del formulario fileupload]

Answer (score 0):

Encontre el problema, al parecer es solo cuestión de deshabilitar el ajax(ajax="false")  en el botón del submit o el botón de aceptar en el caso de español, por eso no llegaba a la llamada del controller.

he decidido ponerlo aquí, por si acaso otra persona le llega a pasar lo mismo y para que me recuerde lo pendejo que puedo ser.

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{formularioController.crearFormulario()}" value="Enviar Formulario" ajax="false" />
```

y pues como no se me ocurrió, no puse en la pregunta el código del botón del submit.
pues con eso me queda claro que hay que poner 4 cosas claras.

1. el p:fileUpload debe estar dentro de un form con el comando enctype="multipart/form-data".

[image: enctype fileupload]

2. en el controller debe pasar el archivo por un tipo de dato compatible con file y luego si hacerle lo que quieras como byte[] como:

[image: Controller para subir el archivo a la bdd]
3. Deshabilitar el ajax en los botones de llamada al controller ajax=false
[image: ajax=false]

4. Poner los filtros en el web.xml

[image: filtros web xml para subir archivos]